# Etymology of a word "Egg" in different languages

Tags: etymology

I would like to know **translations, transcription and etymology of the translations of** a word "**Egg**" in different languages.

I prefer to have answers given in the following form:

- Translation
- Transcription
- Etymology (*if known*)

**One** translation-transcription-etymology **per answer** is preferable.

**EDIT**: The user @jknappen provided me with link on Wiktionary which contains bunch of information on the subject. 
If anyone has relevant information on the cases of languages not included under link of Wikionary it would be wonderful to have it accessible.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of of answering your question directly I will give you a guided tour to some answers.

The starting point of this tour is [the English word egg in the wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egg#English). The entry has an etymology section, and the next stop by is [Proto-Indogermanic root *h₂ōwyóm](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82%C5%8Dwy%C3%B3m). It has an internal possible etymology in the proto-language, and, most relevant to the question, a section of descendants. So you have a lot of words meaning "egg" in different Indogermanic languages at one glance.

Going back to our starting point, we now look for translations of "egg" into other languages. For this tour, I choose Finnish, a language from a different language family, and go to the [Finnish word *muna* "egg"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muna#Finnish). Again, there is an etymology section pointing to [Proto-Uralic *muna](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Uralic/muna), and again, there is a large descendants section giving a lot more etymologies, including Hungarian: (obsolete) *mony*. It has a references section pointing to [entry № 561 in Uralonet](http://uralonet.nytud.hu/eintrag.cgi?id_eintrag=561).

I hope this little tour can help you to discover more etymologies of "egg" on your own.

Answer (score 2):

In Riffian and some other Berber languages: tamellalt < the white (fem.). Other varieties say : tasdelt < del (verb) = blanket.

Answer (score 1):

In Modern standard Arabic the word is (baidhah) بيضة plural is بيض (baidh) 
Etymology: from the color ‘white’