# Finding roots and cognates online

Tags: etymology, reference-request, indo-european

I'm studying linguistics and I want to know if there's an option for having several translations at once?
For example, I enter "word" as an English entry and I get the below output:

- German: word1 word2 word3
- French: word1 word2 word3
- Russian: word1 word2 word3
- Persian: word1 word2 word3

There's https://youtu.be/MEibCyjPMh4 but I need the pronunciation as I can't read the pertaining writing system it uses.

If someone can introduce good online sources I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org)? It offers multilingual translations, frequently with alternatives, and a lot of additional information. The format may be clumsy for automatic harvesting, but for human readers it is very good.

In addition, there is an etymology section to many entries where you can trace ancestors and roots. The roots can be used to find cognates, for a more detailed description see [this answer to another question here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/29027/9781).